# Excel to SharePoint list using Power Automate

Tags: power-automate, sharepoint-list

I am using Power Automate for the first time and I am working on a case that is getting me frustrated cause I just can't figure it out.

I will be exporting sharepoint usage data every 90 days which will be a manual pull.

I created a table in a excel file that contains the data I need from that excel sheet. Every 90 days when I do a new pull, I plan on adding the additional 90 rows to the current table from the first Excel sheet and continue to do so every 90 days, making the original table larger and larger every quarter.

I am trying to create an automate flow where once I go in on the 90th day of every quarter and add the new 90 rows, I can manually trigger a flow and have the new 90 rows added to the SharePoint list from the Excel table.

The Excel table will have the 4 following columns. 'Title', 'Date', 'Unique Viewers', 'Site Visits'.

I made sure that my Microsoft List has the same 4 columns listed exactly the same and they are all in the text format.

[image]

From research, it seems like I need to use the variable functions, get rows, and get item, create item.

My logic is the following:

1. Get rows OR List rows present in a table. Which one should I use?
2. If rows are not already listed in the microsoft list, add to microsoft list.

I appreciate any help with this, I've spent hours and hours trying to get this to work

Comment: You do not appear to have tried either Get Rows or List Rows.